# How to make a LZMA:23 archive?

Tags: archiving, 7-zip, file-archiver

Im trying to make a custom launcher to Minecraft which will be helping with mods. Problem is that the launcher is packed inside a LZMA archive. I can open that archive with 7-zip but I cannot modify it and I cannot make a identical another one so the bootstrap fails to decompress it. The original file can be found here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma .

So, my question is very simple;
How I can make a lzma archive identical to above?

Please do not suggest Google, after four hours it has not helped me anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

7-Zip can extract, but not compress in the file format LZMA. It is on the [7-Zip web page](http://www.7-zip.org/):

> Unpacking only: AR, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DMG, EXT, FAT, GPT, HFS, IHEX, ISO, LZH, LZMA...

You can use the program `lzma` to compress it. I installed it on my computer with `sudo apt install lzma`. The command

```
lzma launcher.pack
```

will create the file `launcher.pack.lzma`.

Comment: I use windows. And I solved the problem, I changed the bootstrapper to download zip files so i can easily make updates. Thanks for your help anyway, didn't know that about 7-Zip.